# How to infer type partially when having multiple generic types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is the original code and the variable `used` has type of `TObject<number, "loi">`, which means `TField` was inferrable with `"loi"`.

```js
type TObject<TItem, TField extends string> = {
    [field in TField]: TItem[];
}

type TProps<TItem, TField extends string> = {
    field: TField;
    items: TItem[];
}

// inferrable 
function useSomething<TField extends string = string>(props: TProps<number, TField>) {
    return {
        [props.field]: [1]
    } as TObject<number, TField>
}
const used = useSomething({ field: 'loi', items: [1, 2, 3] })
console.log(used);
```

Why when I add another irrelevant type `TItem` in the generic list, the type `TField` becomes no more inferrable?

```js
// almost the same as useSomething, only add another type TItem in the generic list
function useSomething2<TItem, TField extends string = string>(props: TProps<number, TField>) {
    return {
        [props.field]: [1]
    } as TObject<number, TField>
}
// TObject<number, string>, but I expect TObject<number, "loi"> as above
const used2 = useSomething2<number>({ field: 'loi', items: [1, 2, 3] })
console.log(used2);
```

- Actual: `TObject<number, string>`
- Expect: `TObject<number, "loi">`

Comment: Unfortunately there is no partial type parameter inference in TS. See the linked question/answer pair.